# Dynamic binding for virtual functions

Tags: c++

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
         cout << "Base class virutal function " << endl;
     }
}

class Derived : public base {
public:
    void foo()
     {
          cout << "Derived class virtual function " << endl;


int main()
{
    Base b, *ptr;
    Derived d;

    ptr = &b;
    ptr->foo();
    ptr = &d;
    ptr->foo();
}
```

Hi,
I have a doubt regarding dymnamic binding here. since compiler knows that when b.foo() is there it can use base virtual fumction. and when d.foo() is present it can use derived version of foo. I mean compiler has every bit of info during compile time but still literature says that which function will be used is decided at run time.

Comment: Did you mean to have your `Derived` class as a child class of `base`? I don't see the inheritance...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `ptr->foo();` somewhere?

Comment: `Derived::foo()` is private !!!

Answer (score 5):

In this *specific* case<sup>1</sup>, the compiler (at least in theory) can determine which function is called in each case, and generate code to simply call the two functions directly (and when I've tested it, most compilers *will* optimize code like this exactly that way).

A more typical case for polymorphism would involve some sort of user input, so the function to be called *can't* be determined statically. For example, using your `Base` and `Derived` classes, consider something like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Base b;
    Derived d;

    Base *arr[] = {&b, &d};

    int i = atoi(argv[1]) != 0;
    arr[i]->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the compiler *can't* determine the correct function to call statically -- depending on what you pass on the command line when you run it, it might use either the Base or the Derived version of `foo()`.

You also seem to have a kind-of intermediate case you started to try to include in your code, but never really completed -- you initialize `ptr` to point at your Base object and then your Derived object, but you never invoke a function via `ptr`, only directly on the objects themselves. If you did invoke the functions via the pointer, it would be *harder* to optimize than when working only directly with concrete objects. Fewer compilers will determine the type statically in this case, but at least some still can/will.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Well, *almost* this specific case anyway. As it stands right now, the code won't compile, because you've defined a class named `base` (lower-case 'b') and tried to instantiate a class named `Base` (upper-case 'B'). Also, your "Derived" class isn't actually derived from `Base`, as you presumably intended. Once those are fixed though...</sub>

Answer (score 5):

In the specific example you give here, you're correct; the compiler has enough information to know which function to call at compile time. The compiler thus does not have to look up the function at run time, but this is a compiler optimization that does not affect the result of the program - the compiler is free to bypass the lookup or not.

Comment: I am sorry i did mistakes in hurry. i have edited it. now in this case compiler have enough info which foo to call where is dynamic binding here

Comment: @user634615: The behavior is that of dynamic binding. The compiler is allowed to optimize the operation if it has enough information but it must guarantee that the results are the same as if the dynamic binding happened at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that compiler can *notice* that you cast `d` to `Base *ptr` and resolve actual function address at runtime?

If yes, where is a sample:

```
if (rand() > 0.5)
{
    ptr = &b;
}
else
{
    ptr = &d;
}

ptr->foo();
```

how can compiler know address at runtime? That's why dynamic binding is there.

Comment: I deleted my answer because of the same faulty logic that Fred Larson pointed out to me. The call is on the object, no t through the pointer.